# Вопрос по строкам в си

Tags: c

**Дано:**
Дана строка символов до точки. Записать новую строку из слов заданной, содержащих букву "M".
Мой код:

```
int main()
{
    char user_words[255];
    char new_str[255];

    printf("Please enter your sequence of words: ");
    fgets(user_words, 254, stdin);
    fflush;

    for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < 255;) {
        if (user_words[i] == '.' || user_words[i] == '\0') break;
        if (user_words[i] == 'm' || user_words[i] == 'M') {
            for (;; i++, j++) {
                if (user_words[i] == ' ') new_str[j] = user_words[i];
                if (user_words[i] == ' ' || user_words[i] == '.') break;
                new_str[j] = user_words[i];
            }
        }
        i++;
    }

    printf("%s", new_str);
    getchar();
    return 0;
}
```

Код работает, но некорректно. Слова нужные выводятся, но без пробелов. Также после вывода нужных слов далее печатается какое то количество мусора и вся начальная строка полностью. В чём проблема? (Начал изучать тему недавно)

Comment: Про пробел понятно — после предыдущего слова `j` указывает в пробел, а следующее слово начинает записываться в том месте, куда указывает `j` — то есть прямо в пробел. Про мусор я догадываюсь, но не совсем понятно — покажите пример, чтобы понятнее было

Comment: Что такое `fflush;` посреди кода?

Comment: Я думал что `fflush` как то повлияет на лишние выводимые символы,но только потом понял что это совсем для другого

Comment: Повлияет или не повлияет, вызов функции в языке С делается при помощи оператора `()`. У вас же просто написано `fflush;`. К чему это?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решение простое же, разбейте строку на лексемы(через strtok) и дампаните их в массив лексем.

Далее бегите по всем словам в массиве лексем и выводите то, что Вам нужно!

Пример кода:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct
{
    char* _str;
    int _size;
} c_string;


c_string GetCharBuf(int size)
{
    char* tmp = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (long unsigned int)size);
    if (tmp)
    {
        memset(tmp, size, ' ');
    }

    c_string c_str;
    c_str._str = tmp;
    c_str._size = size;

    return c_str;
}


int main()
{
    int buff_size = 1024;
    c_string c_str = GetCharBuf(buff_size);
    if (!c_str._str)
    {
        return -1;
    }

    printf("Enter a string : ");

    fgets(c_str._str, c_str._size, stdin);

    c_string* str_arr = NULL;
    int arr_size = 0;
    int i = 0;

    char* tmp_word = strtok (c_str._str,",. ;\t\n");
    while (tmp_word != NULL)
    {
        ++arr_size;
        str_arr = (c_string*)realloc(str_arr, sizeof(c_string) * (long unsigned int)arr_size);
        str_arr[i]._str = tmp_word;
        str_arr[i]._size = (int)strlen(tmp_word);
        ++i;

        tmp_word = strtok (NULL, ",. ;\t\n");
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < arr_size; ++i)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < str_arr[i]._size; ++j) {
            if (str_arr[i]._str[j] == 'M' || str_arr[i]._str[j] == 'm')
            {
              printf("%s ", str_arr[i]._str);
              break;
            }
        }
    }

    printf("\n");

    if (str_arr)
    {
        free(str_arr);
    }


    free(c_str._str);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

1. Для `fgets` можно писать размер массива целиком, он добавляет `'\0'`.
2. Вы не записываете в конец массива `new_str` нулевой символ (`'\0'`), из-за чего `printf` выводит символы пока не встретит его (может быть даже за пределами массива).
3. Пробелам вы не даёте записаться просто потому, что у вас `break` приводит к новой итерации цикла до того как дойдёт до строки, где вы копируете `user_words[i]` в `new_str[j]`.
4. Вместо пробелов (`' '`) используйте функцию `isspace`.
5. Можно переводить символы в нижний или в верхний регистр функциями `tolower` и `toupper` соответственно.
6. Строку с `fflush` удалите, она нестандартная. Пропустить поток ввода можно так: `scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");`.

Comment: Минус не мой, но пункт 6 не будет работать, если в потоке ввода сразу идет `\n`.

Comment: Будет. Пропустить всё, кроме '\n'. Если '\n' нет, то пропускать нечего, затем пропуск '\n'.

Comment: Нет. Ваш `scanf` призван "пропустить всё, кроме `\n`" и затем **пропустить само `\n`**. Как я сказал выше, это не будет работать, если в потоке ввода сразу идет `\n`. Первый формат - `%*[^\n]` - не сможет ничего прочитать и `scanf` сразу завершится с ошибкой. `\n` останется непрочитанным.

Comment: Откуда такие сведения?

Comment: Спецификация `scanf` не является секретом.

Comment: Вот и я про это. Пропустить все кроме новой строки, раз пропускать кроме неё нечего, значит ничего пропущено не будет, а затем будет пропущен конец строки. Что вернет scanf при этом, не имеет никакого значения, т.к. это значение улетит в трубу на следующем statement'е.

Comment: Спецификация функции `scanf` говорит, что если очередному спецификатору формата не удалось проматчить ни одного символа, то это является matching failure и функция `scanf` тут же завершается с ошибкой. То есть форматы `scanf` не умеют "читать" пустые последовательности. Попытка чтения пустой последовательности - это всегда ошибка и досрочное завершение `scanf`. До обработки формата `%*c` в вашем варианте дело не дойдет вообще. Если вы хотите, чтобы ваш вариант работал так, как вы задумали,, вам следует разрезать его на два отдельных `scanf`.

Comment: То, что `scanf` не умеет читать пустые строки через формат `%[]` - странное и неприятное свойство `scanf`. Но такова реальность.